# How to grep multiple strings that starts with certain value

Tags: awk, grep

I have a file consisted of two columns with bunch of numbers, and I'd like to search and find lines in which second column starts with 1.008 or 1.009 or 1.01
but I'd like to have printed both, 1st and 2nd column.

I tried:

```
grep -Ev '^1.008|^1.009|^1.01'
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: So would it be fair to say that you're looking for numbers within a range? If so, you could just use numerical operators with awk, e.g. `awk '$2 > 1.008 && $2 <= 1.01'`.

Comment: `^` matches the start of a line. This pattern doesn't work because it's searching the first column, not the 2nd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When searching one field in tabulated data, `awk` is your golden ticket:

```
awk '$2 ~ /^1.0(0[89]|1$)/ { print $1,$2 }' /path/to/inputfile
```

This will apply the pattern you specify ("starts with `1.009 or 1.009` or is equal to `1.01`") to the second field, and for matches, output the first and second fields.

Comment: Post-edit to the question- if you want to include _any_ value that starts with `1.01`, just remove the `$`.

Answer (score 2):

Assume your file named `exercise.txt` is like this:

```
a   1.008  
b   1.00005  
c   1.01  
d   1.01  
e   1.009
```

```sh
awk '( $2 >= 1.008 && $2 < 1.02 ) { print $1,$2 }' exercise.txt > output.txt
```

Then you have:

```
$ head output.txt  
a   1.008  
c   1.01  
d   1.01  
e   1.009
```

Comment: Don't `cat | awk`; just `awk` the file.  Also, this will fail for potential requested values (e. g. `1.000847`).

Comment: Exactly as DopeGhoti said it fails if I have numbers after 8,9,1. But thanks for trying

Comment: You could salvage this by using something like `awk ( $2 >= 1.008 && $2 < 1.02 ) { print $1,$2 } /path/to/input` though.

Comment: ah ok so i correct the answer after your suggestion @DopeGhoti